# I have a problem with aligning results in python

Tags: python

```
#Very simple frequency checking project 
import random

def rollingadie(x, y) :
    die=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    Ratio=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    random.seed(y)
    for times in range(x) :
        roll = random.randrange(1,7) #roll a die and count the freqeucny and save it on arrary
        if roll == 1 :
            die[0] +=1
        elif roll ==2 :
            die[1] +=1
        elif roll ==3 :
            die[2] +=1
        elif roll ==4 :
            die[3] +=1
        elif roll ==5 :
            die[4] +=1
        elif roll ==6 :
            die[5] +=1

    print(f'Die Face{"Frequency":>13}{"Ratio":>13}')
    for index, value in enumerate(die) :
        print(f'{index+1:>8}{value:>13}{(value/times)*100:>13.1f}') #print out the result of frequency
        Ratio[index]= int((value/times)*100) 
    print()

    print(f'Die Face{"Ratio":>13}{"Bar Chart":>15}')
    for index, value in enumerate(Ratio):
        print(f'{index+1:>8}{Ratio[index]:>13}{"*"*Ratio[index]}') # Display the frequency with *
```

Hi! This probably very simple code for you guys..But I have trouble aligning the print.
[Trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoR23.jpg)

As you can see.. the stars are aligned from left. I want this to start from left and let me recognize
the difference in the number of stars by looking at the right side. How would I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just for a better looking and efficiency,in the for loop you can actually do: ````die[roll-1]+=1````

Answer (score 1):

You just need to flip the alignment character from `>` to `<`:

`f'{index+1:<8}{Ratio[index]:<13}{"*"*Ratio[index]}')`

Comment: Thanks..but I need to make 'Bar' and 'Ratio' to be located at the right and only *s should start from left

Answer (score 1):

Just add a ',' after ratio in second print
Code:

```
import random

def rollingadie(x, y) :
    die=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    Ratio=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    random.seed(y)
    for times in range(x) :
        roll = random.randrange(1,7) #roll a die and count the freqeucny and save it on arrary
        if roll == 1 :
            die[0] +=1
        elif roll ==2 :
            die[1] +=1
        elif roll ==3 :
            die[2] +=1
        elif roll ==4 :
            die[3] +=1
        elif roll ==5 :
            die[4] +=1
        elif roll ==6 :
            die[5] +=1

    print(f'Die Face{"Frequency":>13}{"Ratio":>13}')
    for index, value in enumerate(die) :
        print(f'{index+1:>8}{value:>13}{(value/times)*100:>13.1f}') #print out the result of frequency
        Ratio[index]= int((value/times)*100) 
    print()

    print(f'Die Face{"Ratio":>13}{"Bar Chart":>15}')
    for index, value in enumerate(Ratio):
        #CHANGE
        print(f'{index+1:>8}{Ratio[index]:>13}',f'{"*"*Ratio[index]}') # Display the frequen
rollingadie(19, 6)
```

output:

```
Die Face    Frequency        Ratio
       1            4         22.2
       2            2         11.1
       3            4         22.2
       4            4         22.2
       5            2         11.1
       6            3         16.7

Die Face        Ratio      Bar Chart
       1           22 **********************
       2           11 ***********
       3           22 **********************
       4           22 **********************
       5           11 ***********
       6           16 ****************
```

If you want to add more space between Ratio and bar just put some thing like
 ' ,"   ", ' insted of a ,

Answer (score 0):

You just need to format the asterisks so that they're left aligned:

```
print(f'{index+1:>8}{Ratio[index]:>13}{"*"*Ratio[index]:<}')
```

You may also need to specify the width which you can do dynamically (the following also has spaces for neatness.

```
print(f'{index+1:>8}{Ratio[index]:>13}  {"*"*Ratio[index]:<{max(Ratio)}}')
```